# How do I specify the last column to be copied when moving data between sheets in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

The final goal includes having a table on Sheet1 and when certain criteria is met in the last column of the table, the row is copied to Sheet2 and contents are cleared from that row in Sheet1. What I have now works, and accurately copies and clears the data, but it copies past the last column of the table. Is there a function I can add to limit the number of columns copied? I only want columns A to I copied to the second sheet and then cleared from the first.

This is what I have currently. The reason I want to limit the columns copied and cleared is because I want to have another table next to it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 9 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim r As Long
r = Target.Row
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Sheets("Tasks").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1

If Target.Value = "Complete" Then
    Rows(r).Copy Sheets("Complete Tasks").Cells(Lastrow, 1)
    Rows(r).ClearContents
End If

End If
Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

Comment: So, do you want copying only the first cell of the `Target` cell row and then clear the respective row? Would such an understanding be correct? If so, why do you need the last column? If not, please better describe in words what you try doing.

Comment: You are describing your data somewhat inaccurately. Are these tables (structured) Excel tables? If so, share their names. If not, share their range addresses and refer to them with e.g. `Table1` and `Table2`. You are calculating the last row in `Sheets("Tasks")` yet you are copying to `Sheets("Complete Tasks")`. What's that all about? What is the tab name of the worksheet that contains this code? Please add the requested and any other information to your post. Also, screenshots of your data would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple you have to define a new range without the last column for the row.
Your code may be like this:

(**Cell2Copy** is the new range to copy )

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Cell2Copy as Range
Dim r As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long

If Target.Column = 9 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
r = Target.Row
Lastrow = Sheets("Tasks").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1

If Target.Value = "Complete" Then
    set Cell2Copy = Rows(r).Cells(1,Columns.count-1)
    Cell2Copy.Copy Sheets("Complete Tasks").Cells(Lastrow, 1)
    Rows(r).ClearContents
End If

End If
Application.EnableEvents = True  
End Sub
```

Have a good day.